# Include javascript file at the very bottom of a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails application. There is also a javascript (`javascript1.js`) file that must be include at the very bottom of each view. I put it into /assets/javascripts folder. `Application.js` contains the following code

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= some other files

//= require_directory .
```

Even if don't include `javascript1.js` in `Application.js`, it will be automatically included, won't it?

So how can I do what I want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Separate definition, inclusion and execution of your javascript.

Here's what I would do:

- Wrap your code in `javascript1.js` in a function. Now it doesn't matter when the javascript file is interpreted, as interpreting that file just adds a function for later use
- Add a 'javascript_footer' view to the layout (via e.g. a `render` call or a `javascript_include_tag`), which is then automatically included in every view
- In that footer, call the function defined in `javascript1.js`.

*In response to the first comment:*

Sure, you can can skip steps 1 and 3 and add the javascript to your `layouts/application.html.erb` using e.g.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "javascript1" %>
```

(assuming you are using erb templating and assuming the file is in a location where the `javascript_include_tag` method will automatically find it (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).

*In response to the second comment:*

True, my response to your first comment does not address that. There is no simple way to exclude files from the asset pipeline, as the manifest file explicitly lists what to *include*. A solution is to move everything except for `javascript1.js` to `assets/javascripts/all` and change `//= require_directory .` to `//= require_directory all`. Another, ugly but pragmatic solution is to add `//= require_self` at the bottom and add the contents of `javascript1.js` to the `application.js`

Comment: There should be more simple solution. I just want to include a javascript manually file without using asset pipeline. Is it possible? I'm sure so.

Comment: But, as I said before, "Even if don't include javascript1.js in Application.js, it will be automatically included, won't it?" I don't want it to be included automatically, I want to include it by myself where I want (in my case, it's the bottom of the file).

Comment: Thanks! Can you please also show me how to do steps 1,2 and 3?